# Really useful VB6 source code

Tags: vb6

This isn't a question but I thought I'd start a thread where links to exceptionally useful (and widely applicable) vb6 code could be placed.

My choice is by someone called John Korejwa and is located on planet sourcecode at

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=50065&lngWId=1

Basically what it does is to overcome a serious deficiency in vb6 without resorting to 3rd party components

In vb6 pictures can only be stored as bitmaps. If your application involves capturing and storing images (such as document scans) this can require vastly greater hard disk space than if th images coulsd be stored as jpgs.

That's what this source code provides via a single class that incorporates jpeg compression code.

This limitation is the cause of innumerable questions on vb forums but this is the only code I've ever found that solves the problem just using code inside your vb6 program.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Expect it to be closed.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Very useful code though

Comment: Sure it's a question. Where can you get the best VB6 source code? Good question too, by crikey I will +1 it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/index.asp

More useful VB6 code then you can shake a stick at :)

Comment: Good site. Been playing around with one of the code snippets this afternoon (xp styles in vb6 app)

Answer (score 6):

[Karl Peterson's website](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/)

Comment: Great site! I have found his replacement for Sendkeys for vb6 apps running on Vista invaluable

Answer (score 5):

[Edanmo's list of useful free vb controls](http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/index.shtml).

I especially liked the richedit control which is Unicode compliant.

Answer (score 5):

When mentioned by me in a [different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343380/is-there-any-book-like-c-in-depth-for-vb-net-devs/3343483#3343483), Mark J suggested I moved this here. Still an excellent resource if you want to do high-speed visual basic programming. Originally meant as some kind of competition (with or without "doping") it shows the real strengths and weaknesses of VB6 at its core.

[VBSpeed at XBeat.net](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/)

Answer (score 2):

[FreeVBCode.com](http://www.freevbcode.com/) has always been my favorite place to look before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

[VBNet](http://vbnet.mvps.org/) has a ton of useful stuff.   Definately second the motion on VBAccelerator and Karl Paterson's site.