# Your favorite Visual Basic 6.0 tools and tips

Tags: vb6

This is somewhat related to a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147339/visual-studio-6-tips-and-tricks), but that post was Visual Studio 6 in general and a lot of the suggestions didn't apply to Visual Basic 6.0.

Suggest or vote for tools/tips. Please one tool/tip per post so that everyone can vote on them individually. Include a brief description of what the tools do.

Comment: Please everyone, put a brief description of what the tools actually do in your answer. Folks will not necessarily click your link to the tool's website to find out what it does.

Comment: Locking for historical records.

Comment: This is a constructive question. The answers have no arguments, opinion, debate or extended discussion. There are many facts, references and specific [expertise](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb6/topusers). Do not close this question. Do not delete this question.

Comment: @Sam Saffron can I appeal for this question to be reopened and not deleted please? This is a constructive question. The answers have no arguments, opinion, debate or extended discussion. There are many facts, references and specific expertise. As far as I can judge it's very useful, and for whatever it's worth, I am the [top-voted user on the VB6 tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb6/topusers).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**MZ Tools.**

Free.
Lots of extra tools for the IDE, like "Favorite Procedures" and "Add error routine to prodedure" and lots more.

http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx

Comment: I also love the "show all callers to this routine" and the find command which shows you all results in a docked window. Used to drop out to an external editor to do that before I found MZTools.

Answer (score 72):

Enable mouse wheel in VB6:

[Microsoft:enable the mouse scroll wheel](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=837910)

Comment: Words fail, sorry I can't +5 you.

Comment: I wish I could +1 you over and over again, that's fantastic

Comment: I still have this as: favorite_vb6_addin.zip

Comment: +1 - Couldn't live without this one.

Comment: +1, thankfully there are add-ins that you can use to enable it.  I didn't see the microsoft link, thanks.

Comment: Definitely. I recommended this on a VB6-VB.NET project not too long ago and the developers there were ecstatic. They had been using a 3rd party plugin (don't recall the name) but it didn't work in split windows, whereas the MS one did and felt smoother to them.

Comment: +1, but the MS add-in doesn't work for VBA. At my company we use a free tool Gazanov VBScroll, which works with VBA and VB6 and also works in the SDI mode of the VB6 IDE. http://www.gasanov.net/VBScroll.asp

Comment: @MarkJ - awesome, I could not get the microsoft one working on win7 for some reason. This worked though.

Answer (score 36):

After installing VB6, I always do these customisations on Tools-Options.

- **Switch off Auto Syntax Check** on the Editor tab. You don't want message boxes when you type a syntax error - you just want the problem line shown in red so you can fix it later.
- **Switch on Require Variable Declaration** on the Editor tab. Don't think, just do it.
- **Switch off Compile On Demand** on the General tab. You want to be told about syntax errors immediately when you run your code, not just when the dodgy routine actually gets called.
- EDIT: **Prompt to save changes** when program starts, on the Environment tab. (Thanks wqw for reminding me in the comments.)
- Set **Error Trapping** to "Break on unhandled errors" on the General tab. Actually, this is a personal preference - but you should select the setting that suits you. Hopefully you've worked out an error handling strategy for the VB6 program?
- I have an LCD screen, and the default colours don't work very well, so I change them to lighter ones. I'm also using the [Consolas](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=22E69AE4-7E40-4807-8A86-B3D36FAB68D3&displaylang=en) font. Makes my VB6 code look twenty-first century anyway :)

Comment: Switch Off Auto Syntax Check is GREAT!  Never knew that was a possibility.  That error popup has been bugging me for YEARS!

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about Switch Off Auto Syntax Check either. That is super awesome.

Comment: Somtimes it's convenient to only part complete a line of code while you go and copy an expression and that error message box was a pain in the neck. Thanks!!

Comment: All of these and "Prompt to save changes"

Comment: Very nice. Consolas make vb look way better on the HD.

Answer (score 15):

It's amazing how many people don't use the IDE buttons for commenting-out and uncommenting blocks of source code. They are on the **Edit** toolbar and look like this: [alt text http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/1949/vb6commentbuttons.gif](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/1949/vb6commentbuttons.gif). Right-click in an unoccupied part of the toolbar area and tick the Edit option to display the toolbar.

I once attended an "Advanced VB6" course where the instructor didn't know about those buttons.

---

EDIT: AngryHacker has a [way](http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2009/02/10/5-ways-to-be-a-more-efficient-developer-in-5.aspx) to associate shortcut keys with these buttons to comment and uncomment code blocks at a keystroke.

Comment: Yes, I used those buttons. VERY handy.

Comment: Here is a much better alternative: http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2009/02/10/5-ways-to-be-a-more-efficient-developer-in-5.aspx

Answer (score 11):

I can't believe no one has yet posted [Bruce McKinney's Hardcore Visual Basic (now free online on mvps.org)](http://vb.mvps.org/hcvb.asp)! OK it's a book rather than a piece of software, but it expands to a veritable cornucopia of tools and tips.

Comment: I loved this book. Any other fans will probably also be interested in the ill-fated tale of the third edition, along with errata and sample code:
http://brucem.mystarband.net/mckinney.htm

Answer (score 11):

**SmartIndenter** takes care of all the auto-indenting. It does one thing and it does it really well. And it's free.

http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm

[SmartIndenter http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/1392/screencaps1.jpg](http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/1392/screencaps1.jpg)

Comment: It's a nice tool, but for the love of VB6, don't write ridiculous unindented code to begin with.

Answer (score 7):

The [vbAccelerator website](http://www.vbaccelerator.com). It has so many great examples and free controls with the full source. The site has not been updated in a few years now, but it still keeps running and I still go back to it when working in VB6.

Comment: +1, but you might want to fix the typo in the website name!

Answer (score 6):

I realllly hate checking to see if an array is uninitialized by passing it to a helper function that tries to do a UBound and catches the error if it occurs.

Solution?

Use VarPtr to get the array's address, pass the address to CopyMemory to get the SafeArray structure for the array, if the SafeArray structure indicates 0 dimensions, the array is uninitialized.

**EDIT** thanks to Lance for good link with example

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/helpers/getarraydims.htm

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for exactly that. Here's a link for those interested: http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/helpers/getarraydims.htm

Comment: Long long ago I would have said tricks like this make it harder to upgrade your code to the next version of the language. HA!

Comment: lol I'm laughing because it totally sounds like something I would do. But honestly... Introducing RTLMoveMemory just to avoid testing by exception? I think the risks outweigh the rewards. Especially when your program stops working when MS nukes unsafe API calls.

Comment: Mister, your subscript is out of range.

Comment: @Oorang If you want to debug with Break on All Errors, this is a godsend.

Comment: @Mark Hurd, I'll conceed that point. May stance isn't really "never do that" so much as it is "have a good reason before you do that". That's a pretty good reason:)

Answer (score 6):

[Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) by the GoF. While it doesn't seem specific for VB6 the fact that most of the patterns are based interface implementation and aggregating objects (as opposed to inheritance) makes it well suited for use with VB6. They talk about this on pages 16 to 18 and sum it up in one statement. *Program to an interface, not an implmentation* If there is one thing that VB6 and COM does well is handle interfaces.

Comment: +1. Can I also plug the book "Visual Basic Developer's Guide to UML and Design Patterns" by Griver etc? Explains design patterns in 100% VB6, discussing issues like circular references. Anyone whose main experience is in VB6 might find the gang of four book difficult, I recommend this fine book instead. http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Basic-Developers-Design-Patterns/dp/0782126928

Comment: There is also Microsoft Press's "Visual Basic Design Patterns" by Stamatakis. Personally I hated it (it covers only 7 gang of four patterns and is poorly written). But some folks on Amazon have given it good reviews. http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Visual-Design-Patterns-Professional/dp/1572319577

Answer (score 6):

The entire mvps.org site [here](http://www.mvps.org/)

I recommend Karl Peterson' One stop source and Randy Birch's VBnet (which has nothing to do with VB.NET) and Common Controls Replacement Project.

Comment: Maybe this is more appropriate to the "useful VB6 source code" question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232864/really-useful-vb6-source-code

Answer (score 5):

[Make My Manifest](http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/) can produce Reg-Free COM manifests (chucking in "Styles" as needed, etc.).  This allows XCopy deployment of many VB6 EXEs to WinXP or later.

No more "dependency" fears or DLL Hell!

Comment: Good one!  Also great for producing portable applications that run from a CD or flash memory drive.

Answer (score 5):

The VB6 IDE doesn't remember your preference for maximizing the code windows. To start up with the VB6 code windows maximized, set this string registry key:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0]

"MdiMaximized"="1"

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2008/05/01/vb6-swiss-army-knife.aspx

It has most tools I use for whenever I have to delve into VB6, plus a description of what they do.  In addition to the tools mentioned here, it also has the following:

[PDSA Property Creator](http://www.angryhacker.com/download/pdsaclassbuilder.zip)

[ADO Stored Proc Generator Add-in](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=103)

[Collection Class Master Add-in](http://www.angryhacker.com/download/colclassmaster.zip)

Answer (score 3):

Matt Curlands Power VB book and the VBoost tools that came with it, especially the Type library editor.

Just watch out for the non-DEP compliant techniques.

Comment: The title was "Advanced Visual Basic 6"

Answer (score 3):

The [vbAdvance](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/) add-in is now free.

vbAdvance is a Visual Basic Add-In that gives you access to advanced build features and many IDE convenience features. Create console apps, create standard DLLs that export functions, create a DllMain entry point in your DLLs, XP Manifest compiler for XP styles, Terminal Server, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**CodeSmart 2009 for VB6**

I've not tried this.

http://www.axtools.com/products/cs2k3vb_screenshots.htm

Comment: I have the last version of CodeSmart. It has some useful code analysis features, but I use MZTools 99% of the time and CodeSmart 1%.

Comment: Yeah, MZ Tools is very well done. I"m planning to make a donation.

Comment: I looked @ Codesmart again and it has some really cool code navigation features like hyperlinks amongst code, as well as showing visually which IF a particular THEN goes with, graphically illustrating the flow of CASE statements.
Mztools has cool stuff bit it's a bit hard to access (i.e., to find references : right click, Mztools, sub menu- References, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a lot of things when I was first learning by using the wizards to make forms/small applications, and then examining the code they output.

Answer (score 2):

One great tool that is out there and I've used is called CodeFixer.  I believe I first stumbled across [CodeFixer here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=59247&lngWId=1).

It's even open source.  I have had a little contact with the author, Roger Gilchrist, and he seems to still be working on it in his, surely limited, free time.

Comment: Looks like the author moved the code (or re-listed the new version) at:
 http://www.pscode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=59247&lngWId=1

Also, Ryan, if you include the name codefixer in the link it'll make it easier for folks to find if they google on just codefixer (i.e., gets some google-seo-juice applied to that link for the term "codefixer"

Comment: Thanks for the tip, edited to help the google machine help people.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself yet, but [CodeShine](http://www.wsdesigns.com/CodeShine/default.htm) is a cheap refactoring add-in for VB6. It can do the useful *[extract method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html)* refactoring, apparently.

I must stop wasting time here and download the [free trial](http://www.wsdesigns.com/download.htm) to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 error handling sucks. So I've adopted these patterns to make it easier:

The Try-Catch block:

```
    'Try
        On Error Goto catchX

        ...

    'Catch
catchX: if err.number then
            ...
            resume resumX
resumX: end if
        On Error Goto outside_catch_label_name
    'End Try
```

Including a stack trace in errors:

```
sub rethrow(byval source as string)
    Err.Source = Err.Source & vbNewLine & vbTab & "@ " & Source
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
end sub

sub some_sub: on error goto throw
    ...
throw: if err.number then rethrow("some_sub")
end sub
```

Comment: FYI, MZ-tools (free addon listed in this Question) has a feature to let you automatically add Error Trapping. And you can configure it somewhat like a mail merge. Pretty slick.

Comment: You know I just never got why people don't like VB's error handling. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Oorang: I disliked it because it's too close to BASIC's GOTO/GOSUB roots. For programmers who are used to a more structured try/catch or try/finally style, it feels like a huge step backward. If you like the power and flexibility of GOTO, then enjoy yourself. But you should keep in mind the mental tax you're paying every time you ensure that you've wired up your error handling correctly.

Comment: My favourite error handling method for VB6 was to use HuntERR31 - but I can't find a place to download it anymore. Combined with a custom template for error handling, and a tweak to one of the other IDE plugins to insert the right handler in routines based on their name (broadly, method names with underscores in them are event handlers), and you had the closest thing possible to structured exception handling in VB6 - full stack traces and everything. Went from major headscratching to pinpointing the exact line an error was on. Will see about hosting a copy somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Aivosto's Project Analyzer http://www.aivosto.com/project/project.html

Answer (score 1):

### Spider Eye Flexbag

The collection class replacement from [Spider Eye](http://www.spidereye.com) called [Spider Eye Flexbag](http://www.spidereye.com/software/flexbag) is an absolute must. Its 100% better than the collection classes that ship with VB and its blindingly fast compared to the original collections. The Flexbag collection was written by Gary Wisniewski of "Carl 'n Gary's Visual Basic Home Page" fame.

Unfortunately the Spider Eye website doesn't seem to have a link to the Flex Bag at the moment, but I'm sure if you contact them they'd be happy to sort something out for you. If you are doing any collection based work at all then it would be well worth the effort.

### AVE Code Finder

The [AVE Code Finder](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/CodeDownload/19738) is handy because the Find function in the VB6 IDE can't be trusted. AVE Code Finder is also much much faster then the built in Find. It was written by Jarek Zwierz of [www.ave.com.pl](http://www.ave.com.pl) but the site doesn't seem to exist anymore so the version I've linked to is at VB2TheMax.

Comment: AVE seems to be still alive and kicking : http://www.ave.com.pl/default.aspx?menuid=files&submenuid=s4 : I've also been inspired to send them my personal enhancements to AVE Code Finder - Options for regex, in comment / not in comment, compatibility with VBA, and a couple of minor tweaks like changing the default focus to the combo box and changing the font to the more readable Lucida Console.

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 Credits Easter Egg that lists the development team :)

To show the VB6 Program Credits create an 'About' button to the standard 
toolbar and rename its caption to 'Show VB Credits'. Here's a bit more 
detail:

1. Right-Click on a toolbar and select 'Customize'
2. Within the 'Commands' tab select the 'Help' category
3. Drag the 'About Microsoft Visual Basic' command (right windows of dialog 
   box) up to the end of the standard toolbar.
4. Without closing the 'Customize' dialog box, Right-Click on the button you 
   just created and change its Name to 'Show VB Credits'
5. Close 'Customize' and click the new button.

Bonus points for spotting [famous](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201707128) [names](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321169514).

Answer (score 0):

I purchased the [Codejock SuitePro](http://www.codejock.com) for my company. They have many components to be used in VB6 and C++, including the support to XAML in controls, that is a lightweight version of the WPF.