# Difference between 'Start with full compile' and 'Make Exe'?

Tags: vb6, visual-studio-6

In the VB6 IDE...

> we can compile the project by pressing Ctrl+F5 or by choosing
> File->Make Exe. Is there any difference between these two procedures?
> The former one seems to be a bit faster relatively.
>
> What I want to
> know is "What's difference between these two compilation procedures (if
> any...) and where should I use the first one and where should I use the
> second?"

---

<sub>Based on [this external post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?190345-Difference-between-Ctrl-F5-and-Make-Exe) but added here as a question since I didn't find it on SO.</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate, answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/731187/162313) and here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/667225/162313).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 compiles "on demand" by default which is what happens when you do **Run > Start (or press just F5)**. This means that some compile errors won't reveal themselves until they are actually called at runtime - or maybe not at all if you happen to not execute a particular block of code containing an error.

But using **Ctrl-F5 or "Start with full compile"** causes each and every line of code to be compiled; any potential errors can be revealed and be eliminated this way.

**'Make Exe...'** causes a full compile followed by writing of the EXE of your project.

You can also set some options before compiling when you use 'Make Exe...'
(such as version number).

---

<sub>Paraphrased from [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?190345-Difference-between-Ctrl-F5-and-Make-Exe).</sub>

Comment: It seems like this should be part of your question rather than the being an answer on your question

Comment: @Ruben can you elaborate please?