# Block commenting VB/VB.NET code

Tags: vb.net, vb6

How to comment multiple lines of code/block of code in VB?

Comment: As a side note, you can do block comments in VB.Net (Ctrl-K,Ctrl-C).

Answer (score 38):

VB doesn't have such a construct at the language level. It has single line comments using apostrophe character:

```
' hello world
' this is a comment
Rem this is also a comment
```

However, Visual Studio has a functionality to automate this task. Select the lines you want and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for commenting and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for uncommenting (General Development Settings shortcuts, look at the "Edit `->` Advanced" menu while selecting some code to see the shortcuts).

Comment: Kewl! VS2010 does not have "Edit > Advanced", so the Ctrl-K shortcuts you gave are new to me :)

Answer (score 22):

Totally abusing compiler directives here... but:

```
#If False Then
Comments
go
here
#End If
```

You don't get the benefits of proper code coloration (it doesn't show in green when using the default color scheme) and the implicit line-continuation system automatically indents lines in a paragraph starting at the second line. But the compiler will ignore the text.

Answer (score 15):

The [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068395/commenting-vb-code/1068403#1068403) explain how to comment/uncomment automatically in VB.NET. Just for completeness, in VB6 use these toolbar buttons: [image]. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664370/your-favorite-visual-basic-6-tools-and-tips/667341#667341).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a cludgy way to make a multiline comment which is also collapsible.

```
    If <![CDATA[ Multiline comment about this and that

Comment about this 
and that and so on
with lots of lines

    ]]> Is Nothing Then : End If
```

It looks like this when you collapse it

```
If <![CDATA[ Multiline comment about this and that ...  Is Nothing Then : End If
```

Comment: Does this work for VBScript ? Tried this but got syntax error. (Maybe VB != VBS, n00b here)

Answer (score 4):

Ways you can comment code in VB:

1. by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. adding  **'** (Apostrophes symbol) in front of your code which you want to make it as comment
3. adding `rem` in front of your code which you want to make it as comment.
   **(Note:** `rem` means remarks --> `rem` is used to include explanatory remarks in the source code of a program.**)**
4. just select the particular code and click on the option called **"comment out the selected lines"**  in the toolbar.
5. `#if false` (enter your code here) `#endif`  -- the code inside these 2 statements will be commented.

Answer (score 1):

To comment out a big section of code you highlight the code you want to comment out, then you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. To un-comment a block of commented code you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

in VS2010 VB.NET, type 3 times ' above a class/function/property/declaration

then it will auto generate a comment block :

```
''' <summary>
''' GRP Business partner ID
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
```

same thing in C# but type 3 times /

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the lines that you want to comment.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Visual Studio. It will help you to comment multiple lines at once.

Answer (score 1):

Select the lines you need to comment and press keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If you need to uncomment use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In the vb++ you can comment the blocks of the comment with:

CommentStart==>Type your comment
and on many of the lines<==CommentEnd+/inc.

Answer (score 0):

install MZ-Tools and you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to comment code blocks and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment code blocks.

You can also define your own key-combinations:

[MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Block comments in C-like style /* my comment */ would be useful on e.g. multi-line VB.net statements. They are currently not available.
However, in place of writing

```
myVal = "bla bla bla" /* my comment */ _
      + " more of the same " _
      + " and still more "
```

You could write:

```
myVal = "bla bla bla" + 'my comment
        " more of the same " +
        " and still more "
```

That will work on the later versions of VB.Net.