# multi line comment vb.net in Visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [commenting VB code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068395/commenting-vb-code)
>   [Lack of block comments in VB .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196586/lack-of-block-comments-in-vb-net)

How to?

Is there a way to comment out more than one line of code in vb.net using VS 2010?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The only way is to highlight the lines to comment and press

```
ctrl + k, ctrl + c
```

or after highlighted press the toolbar option to comment out the selected lines.

The icons look like this
[image]

Comment: toolbar doesn't have any option that says comment out. stupid VS. your short cuts Worked!!!

Comment: @gnomixa the icon on my VS is right under the Team link in the tool bar. You might have to go into the options to get it to show up if it is not showing in your Visual Studio.

Comment: what about uncommenting?

Comment: @gnomixa I updated it with what the icons look like in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 21):

I just learned this trick from a friend.
Put your code inside these 2 statements and it will be commented out.

```
#if false

#endif
```

Comment: `#If False Then ... #End If` now required for Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 15):

Highlight block of text, then:

**Comment Block:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

**Uncomment Block:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

*Tested in Visual Studio 2012*

Answer (score 10):

[multi comment in vb.net](http://p2p.wrox.com/vs-net-2002-2003/4077-how-multiline-comment-vbulletin-net.html)

VB.NET doesn't support for multi line comment.

The only way to do multi-line comments in VB.NET is to do a lot of single line comments(`'`).

Or just highlight the whole code and just use `(Ctrl+E,C)`, `(Ctrl+E,U)` to comment or uncomment.

Only in c# `/* */`

Or in ASP.NET html source using `<!-- -->`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could do it in VS 2010 IDE was to highlight the block of code and hit ctrl-E and then C

Comment: Tried in VS2010. Ctrl E and C didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new toolbar and add the commands

- Edit.SelectionComment
- Edit.SelectionUncomment

Select your custom tookbar to show it.

You will then see the icons as mention by moriartyn