# In Visual Basic how do you create a block comment

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [commenting VB code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068395/commenting-vb-code)

Does anybody know how to do a block comment in Visual Basic?

Note: I did a few searches on here and neither those results nor the results for 'Questions that may already have your answer' appeared to ask this question

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There is no block comment in VB.NET.

You need to use a `'` in front of every line you want to comment out.

In Visual Studio you can use the keyboard shortcuts that will comment/uncomment the selected lines for you:

<kbd>Ctrl + K, C</kbd> to comment

<kbd>Ctrl + K, U</kbd> to uncomment

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers (fellow beginners) this isn't a three key combo (like Ctrl+Alt+Del) but rather Ctrl+k, Ctrl+c - without releasing ctrl.

Answer (score 10):

There's not a way as of 11/2012, HOWEVER

Highlight Text (In visual Studio.net)

```
ctrl + k + c, ctrl + k + u
```

Will comment / uncomment, respectively

Answer (score 6):

Not in VB.NET, you have to select all lines at then Edit, Advanced, Comment
Selection menu, or a keyboard shortcut for that menu.

http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/376760-how-block-comment

http://forums.asp.net/t/1011404.aspx/1

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio .NET you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>C</kbd> to comment, <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment a block.