# Development Environment For VBP FIles

Tags: vb6

I come from a C# background but we have an app that is written a long time ago and is a vbp project file

What development enviroment will open that file - I know cls and frm files are class and form files but have never used vbp projects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Visual Basic project file for vb6. Visual Studio should be able to open this file but you will need the VB6 IDE.

Update: As of Visual Studio 2010, VB6 projects are no longer supported. VB6 is still supported by Microsoft, but you will need the specific IDE for it to perform project updates. As of 9 February 2018, this can be found on the [VB6 support site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vb6/vb6-support).

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You need the original VB6 IDE.

Versions of Visual Studio from 2003 - 2010 will attempt to migrate the VB6 to VB.Net, but this usually introduces significant errors which are [difficult to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration?sort=votes).

- If you have an MSDN subscription, you can download Visual Basic 6 free.
- Otherwise try somewhere like eBay, although VB6 is often surprisingly expensive.

Once you have obtained the VB6 IDE, look at the [VB6 IDE tools-and-tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664370/your-favorite-visual-basic-6-tools-and-tips) question for some good tips and free add-ins for improving the development experience.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic 6 creates projects which have the extension `vbp`. I think it stands for Visual Basic Project (obviously).
As Joel suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617486/development-environment-for-vbp-files/3617518#3617518), you can use the VB6 IDE to open the file.

Since you stated that you have a C# background, I take the liberty to assume that you're using Visual Studio. If that's the case, you can open the project with visual studio and it will be automatically upgraded for you.
You must note, however, that the project will be 'upgraded' to VB.NET.

If the project was large and fairly complicated, you'll have to be prepared for quite some time correcting errors. VB6 and VB.NET are quite different you know.

Plus, unless you fix all the errors in the upgraded project, you can't convert the code to C# or any other .NET language.

Answer (score 0):

You need the VB 6 IDE Microsoft Visual studio