# Ye Olde VB6 project: how to recover it?

Tags: vb6

I have to debug an old VB6 project, and I can't manage to open the .vbp file with Visual Studio (even with the help found in some topics)...

My question is simple: how can I do that nowadays?

I'm using VS 2010

Comment: Some extra info would be useful: VS version you use (because 2010 and 2012 are just unable to open vbp's), error messages you get (if any), etc.

Comment: IIRC Visual Studio .NET (i.e. VS7) had an automated VB6 converting tool.

Comment: I'm using VS 2010, and the message is "unable to open Visual Basic 6.0 (.vbp) in Visual Studio." (not exactly the right words, I've translated them from french).

Comment: Well, VS2010 [lost the ability to convert these projects](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/17ef3146-1368-4d09-8efc-1753ddb9fb54), you'll need to dig up an older version of VS somewhere.

Comment: Arg... I was fearing that answer...

Comment: @Nicolas sorry for that :-)

Comment: ^^ Thank you anyway... Let's do it !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Development Environment For VBP FIles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617486/development-environment-for-vbp-files)

Comment: I think you can use Visual studio expess, which is free http://download.chip.eu/en/Visual-Basic-2008-Express_237668.html

Comment: You need the VB6 IDE. Upgrading VB6 to a later version can be a big task. Just debug it in the VB6 IDE, unless its a tiny project.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Visual Studio 2008 to upgrade the VB6 project, and then you can open the upgraded project with 2010.

Be aware that the VB6 project needs to be in a compileable state, and that even so the new project will probably not compile once you are done.

Also be aware that there will likely be some limitations on even a successful upgrade -- ie it almost certainly won't compile for 64 bit systems.

Comment: Indeed... With Visual Studio 2008, the conversion tool creates a ".net compatible project". But... This one is totally useless : there are too many errors such as "TextWidth unknown", "CurrentX is not a member of...", etc. I'm really thinking of developing a new program.. Arf !

Comment: IME, although there are a lot of errors, there are not all that many distinct errors -- ie the same error is repeated many times.  And so they can often be resolved in bulk. For instance CurrentX can probably be fixed by using the printing power pack.