# How to enhance VB6 programming experience?

Tags: vb6

I have an application in VB6 which I am supporting. The only environment that I know of to edit the VB6 project is "Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0" its kind of hard to navigate around compare to the modern editors.

In my projects there are VisualBAsic Module File and a ORIG FILE eg:

mymodule
mymodule.bas.orig

"I will never have to modify the UI just the script"

My first question is is there are alternate Application to modify VB6 project(Without Migrating)?

If not I can see that the module file can be edited using Notepad++. So my second question is can I use Notepad++, sublime, intelij etc. To modify the module then save without any complication(character compatible issues?, file linking issues etc) ? Are there any known issues by doin this? Would you recommend Editing scripts external using a text editor?

Comment: As you've discovered, Notepad++ works fine and you can edit all the various VB6 source text files with it (FRM, BAS, CTL, CLS, etc.)  Beware of changing files outside the VB6 IDE as it won't know you've done it. (Use VBAdvance for this). Overall the VB6 IDE is actually OK for general use even though it pales compared to modern IDEs. The effort to work outside of it but also with it may not be worthwhile.

Comment: I also recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664370/your-favorite-visual-basic-6-0-tools-and-tips

Comment: I use CodeSMART for VB6 widely, it's not that modern but it adds mouse wheel support, tabs & solution wide search (also Ctrl+Shift+F), which is just what I missing in the VB6. It has a lot of other nice features, but three above are the most useful from my experience. Also good plugin is: http://darinhiggins.com/2012/07/26/bookmarksave-addin-for-vb6/, it allows to not loose the breakpoints when you exit VB6.